# easing effect on jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, effect, easing

i am new on stackoverflow and on jQuery..
woundered why the effect of the easing doesn't work for me with jQuery..
the little box is popping up as i want but without the effect i set.

```
<script> 
$('#box').mouseover(function() 
{   
     $('#details').animate({height:'50px', marginTop:'350px'}, 
                        { duration: 600, easing: 'easeInOutBounce' }
     ); 
});
</script>
```

and in the header of the document i set:

```
<script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/jquery-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery.easing.compatibility.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/humanity/jquery-ui.custom.css" /> 
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have to load the easings after jQuery, and easings should be available in jQuery UI if you include them.

Comment: Load jQuery before the easyng and your script should be last in the stack

Comment: am I right that you're using jQuery 1.2?  It's possible the API was different back then, if that's what you're using - the second from the top script

Comment: the jquery 1.2 is what is set on easing dot net.. still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
$('#details')
 .stop()//stop all running animations
 .animate(//start a new animation
   {height:'50px', 
    marginTop:'350px'}, 600, 'easeInOutBounce' 
 );
```